# CakePHP Saving HABTM relationship with same model

Tags: cakephp

I'm having trouble saving some HABTM data.

My model 'Category' has a HABTM relationship with itself called 'SubCategory'

```
$this->Category->create();
$c["Category"]["display_order"] = $this->Category->getNextDisplayOrder();
$c["Category"]["title"] = $this->request->data["title"];
$c["SubCategory"]["category_id"] = $id; //The id of the parent category

$new_cat = $this->Category->saveAll($c);
```

This creates my new category and saves it in the database fine, however the id's are being saved in the wrong order in the subcategory table. 
(category_id => the new cat id i just made, subcategory_id => parent_id)

Any ideas why the ids are being saved in the wrong columns?

This is my HABTM relationship

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'SubCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'joinTable' => 'categories_subcategories',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'subcategory_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Im confused by your post.

if

```
$c["SubCategory"]["category_id"] = $id; //The id of the parent category
```

is this supposed to be the id of the category that was just created or the parent category?  You said two different things in your post.

> (category_id => the new cat id i just made, subcategory_id => parent_id)

Either way, if you want the id to be that of the one you just created change that line to this

```
$c["SubCategory"]["category_id"] = $this->Category->id;
```

or

```
$c["SubCategory"]["category_id"] = $this->Category->getLastInsertID();
```

Comment: I want to create a category, and at the same time, store a relationship to it's parent ($id)